# XML schema validation - Line number always returns 0

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am validating and XML file against a Schema using the following code.

```
Public Sub LoadXml(xmlFilePath As String, xsdFilePath As String)
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(xmlFilePath)
    doc.Schemas.Add(Nothing, xsdFilePath)
    Dim errorBuilder As New XmlValidationErrorBuilder()
    doc.Validate(New ValidationEventHandler(AddressOf errorBuilder.ValidationEventHandler))
    Dim errorsText As List(Of String) = errorBuilder.GetErrors()
End Sub
End Class

Public Class XmlValidationErrorBuilder
Private _errors As New List(Of ValidationEventArgs)()

Public Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ValidationEventArgs)
    If args.Severity = XmlSeverityType.Error Then
        _errors.Add(args)
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetErrors() As List(Of String)
    If _errors.Count <> 0 Then
        Dim ErrorList As New List(Of String)

        For i As Integer = 0 To _errors.Count - 1
            Dim Message As String = _errors(i).Message
            Dim LineNumber As String = _errors(i).Exception.LineNumber
            Dim LinePosition As String = _errors(i).Exception.LinePosition
            Dim combineString = Message & "|" & LineNumber & "|" & LinePosition
            ErrorList.Add(combineString)
        Next
        Return ErrorList
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Any validation errors are stored in a List(Of ValidationEventArgs) and are later processed by the GetErrors function. My problem is that Exception.LineNumber and Exception.LinePosition always returns 0. How can I get the line number and line position of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LineNumber` and `LinePosition` are only available while the `XmlDocument` is initially loading.  They won't get populated if you call `Validate` afterwards.  The reason is that after the document is loaded, it has been converted in to an object graph that no longer maintains the positioning information from the source stream; the original "text" version has been discarded.

To do the validation while loading you need to do something like this:

```
Private Shared Function GetSchemaErrors(fileName As String) As List(Of XmlSchemaException)
    Dim errors As New List(Of XmlSchemaException)()

    Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings()
    settings.Schemas = New XmlSchemaSet()
    settings.Schemas.Add(Nothing, "Path to .xsd file")
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
    AddHandler settings.ValidationEventHandler,
        Sub(sender, args) errors.Add(args.Exception)

    Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, settings)
    Dim doc = New XmlDocument
    doc.Load(reader)

    Return errors
End Function
```